# Change a css class background in css file href Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change a Css file selector class in JavaScript, but the code I am using is not working!

Trying to change this class in my Css -

```
.block-square {
  background-color:rgb(167,128,209);
}
```

I want to change the background-color in this class.

The css href is here `<link id="myStyleSheet" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">` This is where it is located.

Here is my code that is not working:

```
function styleOne() {
    document.getElementById('myStyleSheet').href = 'css/style.css';

    var square = document.querySelector(".block-square");
    square.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
}
```

Please let me know why this code is not working.

Comment: Do you want to swap out your style sheet for another, or change the bg-color of a particular element? The code as written does (or at least attempts to do) both, which would be somewhat unusual.

Comment: Trying to change the background-color on this spread sheet file location.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is not how you work with stylesheets, if you want to manipulate their rules. If you want to know how that works, start reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StyleSheet & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to change the `background-color` of `.block-square`, here is a sample.

```js
$("#styleOne").click(function() {
  $(".block-square").css("background-color", "#FFFFFF");

});
$("#styleTwo").click(function() {
  $(".block-square").css("background-color", "rgb(167,128,209)");
});
```

```css
.block-square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(167, 128, 209);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-square"></div>
<button id="styleOne">StyleOne</button>
<button id="styleTwo">StyleTwo</button>
```

Comment: ha much better.. but yet it can be done with 1 line of code instead of 6 @RamisWachtler

Comment: _“`link` tag doesn't support the attribute `id`”_ – nonsense, of course it does. It says right there on the MDN page you linked to, _“This element includes the [global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes).”_, and `id` is one of them; it can be used on _any_ element.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery, it is much easier.

```
function styleOne() {
  $(".block-square").css("background-color","yellow");
}
```